# The given path's format is not supported in windows app

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried to get file path using below code.

```
string script = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "D:\\Tax Rouding   Projects\\10-12-12 TaxRoundingUtility\\TaxRoundingUtility\\Scripts\\GP_SOP_AdjustTax.sql");
```

But i am getting error : The given path's format is not supported

if i  try to open the file from windows explorer.. i am able to go file location..

```
D:\Tax Rouding Projects\10-12-12 TaxRoundingUtility\TaxRoundingUtility\Scripts\
```

But why i cannot  using c# code...

Any thing i missed in the path...

Comment: I guess your only need to remove `Application.StartupPath + ` in your code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here

```
Application.StartupPath + "D:\Tax Rouding Projects\10-12-12 TaxRoundingUtility\TaxRoundingUtility\Scripts\GP_SOP_AdjustTax.sql"
```

This might end up giving you something like

> "c:\program files\myappfolder\D:\Tax Rouding Projects\10-12-12
>   TaxRoundingUtility\TaxRoundingUtility\Scripts\GP_SOP_AdjustTax.sql"

which is an invalid path. Append only portion of path that you need like (the second part is just an example)

```
Application.StartupPath + @"\TaxRoundingUtility\Scripts\GP_SOP_AdjustTax.sql".
```

Also make sure to escape the '\' in your file path strings.

**Edit**: As Dante has mentioned in the comment in the question, If your target path is fixed and known, you do not need the Application.StartppPath. Just load/read the file for which you have the complete path.